# Using search bar in Google Drive Picker shows no results and throws internal error in network response

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I have the Google Picker API implemented in an application, with the Google Drive view included. Currently, entering a search query in the search bar of the Google Drive view starts showing a drop-down with some file results included, like this:

[search bar drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEY86.png)

However, clicking the "magnifying glass" search button, or pressing enter, or clicking "search for all items containing...", all results in an empty picker, like this:

[empty picker with no search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yVFv.png)

I believe this is occurring because a call to `https://docs.google.com/picker/pvr` is returning this error as a response every time: `&&&START&&&{"error":true,"errorMessage":"Internal error"}`.

The parameters being sent to that /pvr endpoint are here:

```
start: 0
numResults: 50
sort: 3
desc: true
q: testing
cursor: 
mine: 2
service: docs
type: NOT_COLLECTION
options: {"ff":true,"filterTeamDriveResults":true}
token: J********
version: 4
app: 2
clientUser: 1************
developerKey: A*************
subapp: 5
```

What I found is that manually removing the `"filterTeamDriveResults":true` key from the "options" hash and doing an ajax post directly resulted in a successful request, but for whatever reason that option is included with every request from the picker, and any time a request is made with that option included, it seems to fail with the same "Internal error" response. I'm wondering what the source of that option is, and if there's any way to remove it from our picker. As far as I can tell it doesn't seem to be controlled by any of the options in the JavaScript API that we're loading from https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This started happening to us last week as well after having been using the Google Picker API for years without any issues. Your clue about the `filterTeamDriveResults` key reminded me of something I had just read, about [upcoming changes to the Google Drive API and Google Picker API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api):

> Next, we’re introducing a new Drive API resource collection, called “Drives,” to replace the “Team Drives” resource collection. This new resource collection can help you create, delete, get, list and update your shared drives, and features all the same fields, resources and available methods as the “Team Drives” resource collection. If you have been using the “Team Drives” resource collection in your applications, consider migrating as soon as possible as all related fields for Drive API , Drive Activity API and Google Picker API, will no longer be supported starting June 1, 2020.

It doesn't seem related, at least not directly, but made me think that perhaps, [the `SUPPORT_DRIVES` feature](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES) that I had seen here in the docs, could "disable" that other *teamDrive* feature (even though it's not really that, but still...). And indeed, that fixed it. Basically just:

```
new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
  setAppId(appId).
  addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true)).
  enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES)
...
```

One thing to notice is this warning when enabling this feature:

> Before enabling this make sure to refer to [Google Drive API documentation for enabling shared drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-teamdrives) and make any necessary Drive Rest API changes.

Might be relevant in your case.

Comment: Awesome, this did work to enable the search bar. Unfortunately also means we have some work to do to get ready for the shared drive changes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried this and this is not working for me. The filterTeamDriveResults is still going with every request.